# Redirect to previous url after login is not working correctly

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect user to previous URL when user visited before login,After login user will be redirected the page requested.I tried but after login user redirects to a URL that is not valid.So how to get the correct URL to redirect?

### PHP

```
 <?php
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])){

$redirect=$_GET['accesscheck']; 
    function redirect(){
    echo"Please login to continue!";
    }
}
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $loginSuccess = "dashboard/";
        $query = "SELECT username, pass from members where username='$user' AND pass='$pass'";
        $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);

        if ($num_row == 1) {
            if ($_GET['accesscheck'] && TRUE) {
                $url = urlencode($redirect);
            } else {
                $url = $loginSuccess;
            }
            session_start();
            header("Location: " . $url);
        } else {
            header("Location:login.php?attempt=1");
        }
    }

    ?>
```

The page user visted:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    header("Location:../login.php?accesscheck= " . $_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
}
```

at the login page URL is

> http://localhost:8080/site/login.php?accesscheck=%20%2Fsite%2Fdashboard%2Fdiscover.php

after login its an Error coming like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCNYj.png)

Comment: Surely $url=urlencode($redirect); should be using the $_GET['accesscheck'] value. Where does $redirect come from?

Comment: Where does `$num_rows` come from? Why start the session immediately before redirecting? What's the point of `&& TRUE`? Lots of things to consider here.

Comment: I forgot to copy some code @Gavin, Now Check.

Comment: @rjdown please check now.I forgot some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your current url to session

```
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl']=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

Use this to redirect

```
If(isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl'])
 {
      header("Location: ".$_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
  }else{
    //your fixed location
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several bugs in your code. Here's what I think will fix it.

```
if ($num_row == 1) {
    if ( isset($_GET['accesscheck']) ) {
        $url = urlencode($_GET['accesscheck']);
    } else {
        $url = $loginSuccess;
    }
    session_start();
    header("Location: " . $url);
} else {
    header("Location:login.php?attempt=1");
}
```